# Scraping financial data with R and rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to get financial data from morningstar.com; I want to get [i.e. MSFT yearly revenue data](http://financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=MSFT&region=usa&culture=en-US).
They are in a row `<div>`of a main `<div>` table.
I followed some samples to get the main table:

```
url <- "http://financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=MSFT&region=usa&culture=en-US"
table <- url %>%
 read_html() %>%
 html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="sfcontent"]/div[3]/div[3]') %>%
 html_table()
```

but I get an empty `list()`. `html_nodes` itself returns a `{xml_nodeset (0)}` that I don't know how to handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
read.csv("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?&t=XNAS:MSFT&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&curYearPart=1st5year&rounding=3&view=raw&r=865827&denominatorView=raw&number=3", skip=1)

   Fiscal.year.ends.in.June..USD.in.millions.except.per.share.data. X2011.06 X2012.06 X2013.06 X2014.06 X2015.06      TTM
1                                                           Revenue 69943.00 73723.00 77849.00 86833.00 93580.00 90758.00
2                                                   Cost of revenue 15577.00 17530.00 20249.00 26934.00 33038.00 31972.00
3                                                      Gross profit 54366.00 56193.00 57600.00 59899.00 60542.00 58786.00
4                                                Operating expenses       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
5                                          Research and development  9043.00  9811.00 10411.00 11381.00 12046.00 11943.00
6                                 Sales, General and administrative 18162.00 18426.00 20425.00 20632.00 20324.00 19862.00
7                             Restructuring, merger and acquisition       NA       NA       NA   127.00       NA       NA
8                                          Other operating expenses       NA  6193.00       NA       NA 10011.00  8871.00
9                                          Total operating expenses 27205.00 34430.00 30836.00 32140.00 42381.00 40676.00
10                                                 Operating income 27161.00 21763.00 26764.00 27759.00 18161.00 18110.00
11                                                 Interest Expense   295.00   380.00   429.00   597.00   781.00   869.00
12                                           Other income (expense)  1205.00   884.00   717.00   658.00  1127.00   883.00
13                                              Income before taxes 28071.00 22267.00 27052.00 27820.00 18507.00 18124.00
14                                       Provision for income taxes  4921.00  5289.00  5189.00  5746.00  6314.00  5851.00
15                            Net income from continuing operations 23150.00 16978.00 21863.00 22074.00 12193.00 12273.00
16                                                       Net income 23150.00 16978.00 21863.00 22074.00 12193.00 12273.00
17                      Net income available to common shareholders 23150.00 16978.00 21863.00 22074.00 12193.00 12273.00
18                                               Earnings per share       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
19                                                            Basic     2.73     2.02     2.61     2.66     1.49     1.51
20                                                          Diluted     2.69     2.00     2.58     2.63     1.48     1.50
21                              Weighted average shares outstanding       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
22                                                            Basic  8490.00  8396.00  8375.00  8299.00  8177.00  8114.00
23                                                          Diluted  8593.00  8506.00  8470.00  8399.00  8254.00  8183.00
24                                                           EBITDA 31132.00 25614.00 31236.00 33629.00 25245.00 24983.00
```

It's super-helpful to make browser Developer Tools "Network" tab your BFF.

(that URL came from inspecting what the "Export" button does).

Answer (score 1):

Stefano, you will probably find this to be very useful.

```
require(quantmod)
setwd("C:/Users/your_path_here/")
stocks <- c("AXP","BA","CAT","CSCO","CVX","DD","DIS","GE","GS","HD","IBM","INTC","JNJ","JPM","KO","MCD","MMM","MRK","MSFT","NKE","PFE","PG","T","TRV","UNH","UTX","V","VZ","WMT","XOM")

# equityList <- read.csv("EquityList.csv", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# names(equityList) <- c ("Ticker")

for (i in 1 : length(stocks)) {   
        temp<-getFinancials(stocks[i],src="google",auto.assign=FALSE)
        write.csv(temp$IS$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Income_Statement(Annual).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$BS$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Balance_Sheet(Annual).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$CF$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Cash_Flow(Annual).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$IS$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Income_Statement(Quarterly).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$BS$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Balance_Sheet(Quaterly).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$CF$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Cash_Flow(Quaterly).csv",sep=""))
}
```

Comment: Thanks ryguy72. I prefer morningstar.com key ratios because there are 10 years of data while yahoo and google only 5.