# Errorr when trying to scrape financial data with R from morningstar.com

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from morninglory in R. I've found a way in a different 
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981137/scraping-financial-data-with-r-and-rvest), but its not working for me.

```
read.csv("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?&t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&curYearPart=1st5year&rounding=3&view=raw&r=374886&denominatorView=raw&number=3")
```

Everytime I try this I get the following error in R:

"Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input"

Has anybody an idea how to resolve that issue?

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: There is an export button on http://financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=MSFT&region=usa&culture=en-US. What happens, if you click it? Hint: Open your developer tools and observe the network.

Comment: Hi @Kluddizz, thank you for your answer. I was doing exactly that, and that is the place where I got the URL from. The exported csv contains the data, but in R it is not displayed. Maybe you know what to do.